# sum of series 1*3-3*5+5*7

Tags: php, math, sum, series

please help to print series as well sum of series like 1*3-3*5+5*7 up to n terms i have used code like this in php

```
class series {
    function ser(){
        $i = 0;
        $k = 3;
        $m = 0;

        for($j = 1; $j < 3; $j++) {
            if($j % 2 == 0 ) {
                $m = $i + ($i * $k);
            } else {
                $m=$m-($i*$k);

            }
        }

        //$m = $m + $i;
        echo "$m";
    }
}

$se = new series();
$se->ser();
```

Just i have tested for 2 times

Comment: Step 1:  Format your code so that it is readable.  Step 2:  Tell us what language this is.  Step 3:  Don't use a member function when a non-member function will suffice.

Comment: You should click the green checkmark next to the answer to mark it as correct and give credit.

Comment: This must be PHP! so please add PHP to the tags and remove other ambiguous tag names(sum series mate). Homework is a must if this is indeed a homework question:)

Answer (score 8):

With a few simple operations one can find a formula for the sum S.
If n is even (sum Se) adding pairs of terms yields

```
 Se = (1*3 - 3*5) + (5*7 - 7*9) + (9*11 - 11*13) ...
 Se = -4*(  3 + 7 + 11 + ...  )
```

The terms in the parenthesis can be splitted and summed up:

```
 Se = -4*( 1+2 + 3+4 + 5+6 + ...  )
 Se = -4*( n*(n+1)/2 )
 Se = -2*n*(n+1)
```

If n is odd (sum So) the last term must be added to Se:

```
 So = Se + 4*n*n-1
 So = +2*n*(n+1) - 1
```

The implementation in C:

```
int series ( unsigned int n )
{
  if ( n%2 == 0 )
    return -2*n*(n+1);
  else
    return +2*n*(n+1) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Doing some math on paper before rushing to implement tons of loops : that's real optimisation !

Answer (score 5):

This is probably homework, but here goes anyway. Hopefully you learn something from this.

The code above is horrible. Over-complicated for nothing... Here's a very simple version for you. I have no idea of what language this is in, but I'll do something similar for you... Go get a book on programming, that will be a wise investment of your time.

```
function my_sum(int $count) {
    $result = 0;
    $sign = 1;
    for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
        $result = $result + $sign * (2*$i-1) * (2*$i+1);
        $sign = - $sign;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Hope this helps... You probably get the idea with this.

Comment: You realise he probably just copy/pasted this answer without reading it or understanding it?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the recursive function and by this way you can stackoverflow (woot!) :) :

```
public static int serie(int n){
    if(n<1){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return (n%2==0?-1:1)*(4*n*n-1)+serie(n-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, use the following to compute the first n terms of your series.  Sorry haven't figured out how to make SO display LaTeX properly, perhaps someone can edit it for me, but if you do please leave a comment with instructions please !

\frac{1}{2} \left(-4 (-1)^n n^2-4 (-1)^n
   n+(-1)^n-1\right)

Or, as generated by the wonderful [EquationSheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/textoimage.php):

[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/6140ef506f6900c756703d4422349361.gif))</sub>

Comment: I hope you find that site as helpful as I do, Mark.  Just paste in your LaTeX, copy the URL of the generated image, and add it to your SO posting as an image.  Brilliant stuff.